# Upcoming exam! Any good sources to learn about counting techniques and discrete probability?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, intuition

If anyone has a free, online source to contribute for a certain topic/topics, please share!  I'm not really looking for an intense theoretical grasp of these topics, just an intuitive understanding of how they work and how they can be applied to practical problems.

Counting stuff

1. The pigeonhole principle.
2. Permutations/combinations.
3. Binomial coefficients.
4. Generalized permutations/combinations (repetition, indistinguishable objects, etc.).

Probability stuff

1. Probability theory (conditional probability, independence, Bernoulli trials/distributions, random variables).
2. Baye's theorem.
3. Expected value and variance.

Anything to contribute would be extremely helpful.  Even posts on the StackExchange website can help tremendously if they're relevant.

Thank you all for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find some interesting materials in this site:

http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/

The following notes are rather interesting

http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/notes/counting.pdf

http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/notes/comb.pdf